# Random breakpoints during debugging Ruby code on RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

My application runs correctly when I start it up in debug mode. The following message shows up on the console:

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.6.1.beta2, debase 0.2.2.beta7, file filtering is supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:59678
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

When I add any breakpoint, the debugger stops at random lines in ruby's code. And the following comes up on the console:

```
/Users/shiladityamandal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:198:in `each'
/Users/shiladityamandal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:198:in `block in start'
/Users/shiladityamandal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
/Users/shiladityamandal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
/Users/shiladityamandal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
/Users/shiladityamandal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
```

Has anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: Nope, and I use it a lot... Is the .idea directory in version control? If so, perhaps they are someone else's breakpoints.

Comment: no it is not in version control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetbrains support suggested a solution which worked for me:
downgrading debase gem from 0.2.2-beta7 0.2.2-beta6

Existing issue link:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-17990

Comment: THANK YOU! This was driving me batty. According to that link, the problem has been fixed in 0.2.2-beta8. I tried it, and it works.